# Character String Conversion using Python

Tags: python, chinese, text-manipulation

Hi I have a website that is in Traditional Chinese and when I check the site statistics it tell me that the search term for the website is å%8f°å%8d%97 è¦ªå­%90é¤%90å»³ which obviously makes no sense to me. My question is what is this encoding called? And is there a way to use Python to decode this character string. Thank you.

Comment: there was an answer here but it has disappeared!! What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on stackoverflow and got the following answer. The solution works like a charm.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316766/decoding-unknown-encoded-traditional-chinese-character-strings-using-python